# sql table index

Tags: sql, indexing

i am having a hard time to understand what indexes I should create.

I made this sample query that contains various situations (select, join, group, order etc..).
What index/indexes should i create on this sample?

Table A: 2 gb in size

Table B: 100kb in size

```
SELECT A.AAA, A.BBB, A.CCC, B.mycol 
From tableA as A 
INNER JOIN tableB as B
ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE AAA='3' 
AND BBB>'2021-10-10'
AND CCC<'2021-11-01'
GROUP BY B.mycol, A.AAA, A.BBB, A.CCC
ORDER BY A.AAA desc
```

my understanding would be that i have to create one single inxed, with the clumns A.ID, A.AAA, A.BBB, and A.CCC. Table B does not need a index becuase it is small and wouldnt make any change.

is this correct? or do i need to create multiple indexes?

Comment: Since you have different queries you need separate indexes for these columns.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: You may remove the `GROUP BY` line as it isn't doing anything.

Comment: telling us the physical size of tables is a little meaningless, the usefulness of an index comes down to the number of rows and the data cardinality / distribution, and you should always implement a unique clustered index / pk in (almost) all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to optimize execution time on the query:

```
SELECT A.AAA, A.BBB, A.CCC, B.mycol 
From tableA as A 
INNER JOIN tableB as B
ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE AAA='3' 
AND BBB>'2021-10-10'
AND CCC<'2021-11-01'
GROUP BY B.mycol, A.AAA, A.BBB, A.CCC
ORDER BY A.AAA desc
```

Since this query is filtering data using columns in `tableA` only, then `tableA` will be the driving table.

In the driving table we need to include the filtering columns, considering equality filters first, then non-equality filters, from highest to lowest selectivity. In this case:

- AAA
- BBB
- CCC

The `GROUP BY` clause isn't doing anything, so we'll ignore it.

The index above will provide the rows in the order required by the `ORDER BY` clause, that the engine will walk backwards. Therefore, there's no need to tweak the index for this purpose.

Finally, the engine will perform a nested loop to retrieve rows from `tableB`. In order to do this efficiently the query will need and index by:

- ID
- mycol (optional, if we want a covering index for higher performance)

In short you'll need the following two indexes:

```
create index ix1 on tableA (AAA, BBB, CCC);
create index ix2 on tableB (ID);
```

Please consider the engine mat ignore them anyway, if the histograms of the table say otherwise.

Comment: thank you very much.. i wrote the sample query without much knowledge in sql, so if we change the groupby in a way that it actually does something, how would that affect my indexes? is the order of the select compared to the order of the group by also important?

Comment: @sharkyenergy SQL is a declarative language, so the every detail can push the engine to decide on a different strategy. If the query changes, then it would be a totally different animal to optimize. I would suggest you ask another question, since the answer can be radically different.